# What does a Type-Import-on-Demand Declaration import?

Tags: java, import

In Java, there are two valid forms of the `import` declaration:

- `import java.lang.Math;`
- `import java.lang.Math.*;`

In the latter, a wildcard is used. This form is known as a Type-Import-on-Demand declaration, but how is it different from the former? Does it also import the subpackages of `java.lang.Math`?

What if `Math` were a Type (*e.g.*, a class)—would all of its inner classes be imported?

Comment: `import java.lang.Math` is redundant. You don't have to import things in `java.lang` .

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am aware of that we don't have to import java.lang but my question is what's the difference between two import statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only immediately-nested types are imported. The declaration is not recursive.

This does work with types for importing inner classes.This also works with static import (for importing methods).

```
import static a.b.c.FooBar.*;
```

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) states:

> Note: Another, less common form of import allows you to import the public nested classes of an enclosing class. For example, if the graphics.Rectangle class contained useful nested classes, such as Rectangle.DoubleWide and Rectangle.Square, you could import Rectangle and its nested classes by using the following two statements.
>
> ```
> import graphics.Rectangle;
>
> import graphics.Rectangle.*;
> ```
>
> Be aware that the second import statement will not import Rectangle.

So importing `import  java.lang.Math.*;` will not import the `Math` class.

**NOTE**: You may also want to see [Why is using a wild card with a Java import statement bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad)

Answer (score 3):

`import  java.lang.Math.*;`

This will import all nested classes declared in the `Math` class in the `java.lang` package. References to nested classes could be given without the outer class (e.g., `Foo` for `java.lang.Math.Foo`).

`import  java.lang.Math;`

This will import the `Math` class in the `java.lang` package. References to nested classes would have to be given with the outer class (e.g., `Math.Foo`).

Comment: are there more classes within Math class ?

Comment: @bharatbhushan Nope. It's a pointless statement, but it is syntactically valid, and could be used in other circumstances. Stylistically, I recommend avoiding wildcard imports all together. A modern IDE will have an option for converting wildcard imports to individual imports automatically, which is quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
import java.util.ArrayList.*;
```

imports all nested classes of ArrayList, but not ArrayList itself. Since ArrayList does not have any (public) nested classes, the statement actually does nothing.

However, consider the interface `Map`, which defines the nested class `Map.Entry`. If we write

```
import java.util.Map.*;
```

at the start of the Java file, we can then write `Entry<A,B>` instead of `Map.Entry<A,B>` to refer to this nested class.

Importing members of classes usually makes the most sense if you are using *static imports*. Then you don't import nested classes, but static methods and variables. For example,

```
import static java.Math.*;
```

will import all static constants and methods from the `Math` class. Then you can use the static methods of the `Math` class by writing, e.g. `sin(x)` instead of `Math.sin(x)`.

Comment: The matter is not only about *nested classes*, but also *const* and *methods*.

Comment: @GiulioBiagini Only if you write `import static`. With only `import`, only classes are imported.

Comment: But okay, I extended my answer although the OP didn't ask about static imports.

Comment: Yes, but you will seldom need to import nested classes. For clarity it, is good to also specify the behavior that occurs in presence of the key *static*, that allows you to use *const* and *methods* without writing the class name before them. For sure, it will be more useful for the user to know this behavior rather than the other.

Answer (score 1):

With the statement `import java.util.ArrayList.*;` you will import all nested classes declared into `ArrayList` class.

If you also want to import methods and const, for example, declares:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

Then you can use the *constant* `PI` in your code, instead of referencing it through `Math.PI`, and the *method* `cos()` instead of `Math.cos()`. So, for example, you can write:

```
double r = cos(PI * theta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically Math is a final class, and it does not have further sub classes. There is no difference between `import  java.lang.Math.*` and `import java.lang.Math` Both are one and the same. So I really dont see the need here to use the first kind of import.