# importing instance members(not static members) from a class to another class using import statement

Tags: java

Can i access all the members(both static and instance) in a class using like this

```
import java.lang.System.*;
```

If i want to import a class then syntax should be `import java.io.PrintSteam`
Then we can access printstream and for accessing static members import static should be used

`import java.lang.System.*` is compiled successfully but not able to access any methods,instance variables,static variables from the class,then what is imported using above line.

Comment: @ernest_k,Thank you,yes,static is for importing static members,how to import instance members into other class. import java.lang.System.*; is compiled,what is imported if not instance members

Comment: You can't import instance members like that, simply because the instance on which to call/read them is unknown.

Comment: @GhostCat,Question is different,Please  explain what is imported using import java.lang.System.*;

Comment: @ernest_k,ok but why import java.lang.System.* is compiled and what is imported ?

Comment: Yes,import would not fail ,but why the compiler successfully compiles import java.lang.System.*; and what is imported?

Comment: I think I understand your 'why' question better. Compilation doesn't fail because the wildcard doesn't match anything. But it would be valid because `System` could have nested types (which could be possibly targeted by the `System.*` import).

Comment: @ernest_k,Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with *why* it is valid.

Quoting the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-7.html#jls-TypeImportOnDemandDeclaration):

> TypeImportOnDemandDeclaration:
>
> import PackageOrTypeName . * ;
>
> The PackageOrTypeName must be the canonical name (§6.7) of a package, a class type, an interface type, an enum type, or an annotation type.

The JLS says it valid to "import on demand" (wildcard import) a **type**, (such as `java.lang.System`).

Why does that make sense? Because a class (type) can have **inner** classes.

So when you have

```
public class A {
  public static class InnerB
```

the `import A.*` will make that `InnerB` available. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548402/what-does-a-type-import-on-demand-declaration-import) for more thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static import like below.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
```

Comment: I think OP's question is different. What is the purpose of import java.lang.System.*; if there is no purpose then why the compiler does not complain.

Comment: @AmitBera,Thank you that's excatly i'm trying to figure out  :)

Comment: @ShashaankVV Would you mind updating the question if this is what you are looking for? The question never suggests this.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan,Thank you for the suggestion,question updated