# Import some classes in same package

Tags: java, class, import, package

I want to import all the classes in a package at once, not one by one.
I tried `import pckName.*;` but it's not working.

Example: I have class X in package name pack1.

```
package pack1;

public class X {
.
.
}
```

and I have class Y in the same package.

```
package pack1;

public class Y {
.
.
}
```

I don't want to have to import them like this:

```
import pack1.X;
import pack1.Y;
```

Why? Because my package (har!) has a lot of classes and it's annoying to add them one by one.
Is there a way to import them all at once?

Comment: `import pack1.*;` would work

Comment: import pack1.*; should work. Why are you saying it is not working?

Comment: actually that what i thought , i tried to do that but the eclipse mark me a red line under the class name. and when i hover the mouse there is 1 option : "Explicity import pack1.X;"

Comment: might be a misconfiguration of eclipse

Comment: I guess you are having the same class X or Y is defined in two different packages.

Comment: It's usually considered bad practice to import by wildcard (import `pack1.*`). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use:

```
import pack1.*;
```

Add this line to the classes from the other packages.
E.g.:

```
package pack2;

import pack1.*;

public class XPack2 {
    // ...
    // X x = new X();
    // ...
}
```

Just make sure, that your **classpath** is correctly set.

Problems can arise, when you have *2 classes with the same name*: `pack1.X` and `pack2.X`.

Then you should explicitly write fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: how do i check if the classpath is correctly set? maybe that is the problem because the classes was originaly build outside the package, then i create the package and grabbed all the classes to the that package.. but how do i fix that?

Comment: If you develop in eclipse, check your ```Build Path```: Project properties --> Configure Build Path.

Or simply select the project and click [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[O]. This will automatically resolve all import issues.

Comment: I think the problem is that i created the classes outside the package and only then i grabbed them into the package. but how should i fix that? i dont want to create them again.

Comment: Just fix all the red bullets in eclipse. Add correct package declarations to all the classes and then organize imports.