# Main method wont compile cannot find symbol to create an object

Tags: java

im new to java so I imagine this is a very simple question but I cannot find my answer

Im creating a very simple game but when i come to compile my main I get

```
 BattleShipGame.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
 BattleShip ship = new BattleShip();
        ^
 symbol:   class BattleShip
 location: class BattleShipGame

 BattleShipGame.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
 BattleShip ship = new BattleShip();
                          ^
  symbol:   class BattleShip
  location: class BattleShipGame
  2 errors
```

So when i go to create my object in the main it cannot find the symbol and create the object

My battle ship class :

```
public class BattleShip {

//delcare an int arry to hold the location of the cells 
private int[] location;

//setter for location 
public void setLocation(int[] shipLocation){
    location = shipLocation;
}

public String checkGuess(String[] g){

//return the message
return message;
}

}
```

Main method :

```
public class BattleShipGame {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create a battle ship object 
    BattleShip ship = new BattleShip();
    //hard code location of ship
    int[] ShipLocation = {4,5,6};
    //set the location of the object
    ship.setLocation(ShipLocation);
    //take the users guess from command line
    String[] guess = {args[0], args[1], args[2]};
    //take message returned from method
    String message = ship.checkGuess(guess);
    // print out the message
    System.out.println(message);

    }
 }
```

If anyone could let me know why i cant create an object?

I compiled the battleship class before the main 
These are both in the same package do I still have to import?

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: have you imported the Battleship class?

Comment: Import the BattleShip class in BattleShipGame class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure about two things:

1. You should compile your `BattleShip` class first before using it in your `BattleShipGame` game
2. If both `BattleShip` and `BattleShipGame` classes are not in the same `package` then you need to import the `BattleShip` class in your `BattleShipGame` class using import statements.

Comment: Given what we're seeing, I suspect that not having `BattleShip` compiled is the immediate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Imports are missed.

```
   //imports missing here

public class BattleShipGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create a battle ship object 
        BattleShip ship = new BattleShip();
```

To Use that object you have to `import`

I suggest you to use an  IDE that corrects your compile time errors and saves a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `import com.your.package.BattleShip` in `BattleShipGame.java`.

Use for example Eclipse or any other IDE, which will manage imports for you. In Eclipse the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put both file in a single directory. Suppose you put both files in different directory say `Game` and `Main`. then in main file add this line in starting `import Game.BattleShip;` and add this line in BattleShip class file in first line `package Game;`

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Using a wild card with a Java import statement is not recommended. [Reference.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad)

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Thanks for the link. Appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write booth classes in same directory or use import statement in `BattleShipGame` class

```
import com.test.BattleShip;

public class BattleShipGame {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     BattleShip ship = new BattleShip();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure quite what was wrong I moved the files out of the netbeans created project and it all worked fine , thanks for your answers though

Answer (score 0):

Try to run code using right click on Main.java and click run instead of compile using terminal. Otherwise you need to compile other classes before main class.

Comment: Their filename is not Main.java. Also, they've mentioned in one of the comments that they are using netbeans IDE which compiles the code automatically and no action is required.