# Android OpenGL ES2 imports for renderer?

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl-es-2.0

I'm new to Open GL ES2.I want to create a sample renderer.I override this method:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Then I got this error:

> The method glClearColor(float, float, float, float) is undefined for
>   the type

I try `ctrl+shift+o`  but no thing happend.Until I add these lines to imports:

```
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClear;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClearColor;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glViewport;
```

And error rmoved.Why `ctrl+shift+o` does not organize imports automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcard import like `import static android.opengl.GLES20.*` to import all stuff for sure but this is often considered to be a bad practice in Java - you can read more here [Why is using a wild card with a Java import statement bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad) and make your own mind. But I'd better suggest you to call GL commands with `GLES20.glClearColor(...)`.

Comment: Note that `GL_`/`gl` is already a namespace in its own right, no need to add yet another prefix like `GLES20.`. Moreover, when you decide to upgrade to newer GLES version, you'll have to fix almost every line of your source code, and this is ugly.