# Cannot find symbol assertEquals

Tags: java, class, testing, junit, symbols

I'm trying to write my first unit tests for a calculator, but NetBeans says it can't find the symbol `assertEquals` and annotation `@Test`.
Should i include something?
I'm using NetBeans 7.3.1 and W7.

```
package calculator;

import org.junit.Assert.*;

public class UnitTests{

    @Test
    public void checkAdd(){
        assertEquals(2, Calculator.rpnCalc(" 2 3 + "));
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks guys, importing it as static helped.
 Test annotation required only including

> import org.junit.Test;

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`assertEquals` is a static method. Since you can't use static methods without importing them explicitly in a static way, you have to use either:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
...
Assert.assertEquals(...)
```

or:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
...
assertEquals(...)
```

For `@Test` it's a little bit different. `@Test` is an annotation as you can see by the `@`. Annotations are imported like classes.

So you should import it like:

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Generally avoid using wildcards on imports like `import org.junit.*`. For reasons see [Why is using a wild card with a Java import statement bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad).

Answer (score 42):

## JUnit 5 *Jupiter*

In JUnit 5 the package name has changed and the Assertions are at `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions` and Assumptions at `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions`

So you have to add the following `static import`:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
```

See also http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions

Comment: wow, this worked. With the JUnit 4 static imports,  `import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;` I was able to pass the unit test in the IDE. But when I run maven install, it complains Noclassdefound. I replaced with `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;` and it works like a charm now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 11):

I am working on JUnit in java 8 environment, using jUnit4.12

for me: compiler was not able to find the method assertEquals, even when I used
    `import org.junit.Assert;`

So I changed 
`assertEquals("addb", string);`
to
`Assert.assertEquals("addb", string);`

So if you are facing problem regarding `assertEqual` not recognized, then change it to `Assert.assertEquals(,);` it should solve your problem

Comment: If you're not using a **static** import directly on the `assertEquals` method, you can't use it in your code without the class `Assert`, see my answer!

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem `cannot resolve symbol Assert` i have tried these solutions by adding the different import from the different answers.

1. import org.junit.Assert;
2. import static org.junit.Assert.*;
3. import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
4. import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
5. import org.junit.Assert;

but the solution that did the magic was just place the `junit-4.12.jar` in the `app\lib` ditectory and just build the project, and import like this

```
import org.junit.Assert;
```

you can download the  `junit-4.12.jar` from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar)

Comment: yes @Ali your right we can manage by adding jar file to libs folder

Answer (score 1):

Using IntelliJ 2019.2.4 with a start.sping.io default setup...

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
```

but now instead of

```
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

use

```
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the dependency to pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>          
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>            
  <version>4.12</version>       
</dependency>
```

Comment: The Question contained a hint from 6 years ago that the missing "import static" was the actual problem, so your answer is missing the point I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

my project is based at maven,although I editor junit in the pom.xml,I still can't find junit in my repository,so I download the junit.jar into my repository.It works!you can try it!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30279049)