# Error with import of org.junit.Assert

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm having a little problem with a unit-test my professor gave me. Upon compilation, I recieve the following errors:
`cannot find symbol import org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
cannot find symbol import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;`

I have downloaded JUnit and I can compile a similar file, so why am I having problems with this?
The code is:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

    public class SortingTests {

      class IntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
          return i1.compareTo(i2);
        }
      }

      private Integer i1,i2,i3;
      private OrderedArray<Integer> orderedArray;

      @Before
      public void createOrderedArray(){
        i1 = -12;
        i2 = 0;
        i3 = 4;
        orderedArray = new OrderedArray<>(new IntegerComparator());
      }

      @Test
      public void testIsEmpty_zeroEl(){
        assertTrue(orderedArray.isEmpty());
      }

      @Test
      public void testIsEmpty_oneEl() throws Exception{
        orderedArray.add(i1);
        assertFalse(orderedArray.isEmpty());
      }


      @Test
      public void testSize_zeroEl() throws Exception{
        assertEquals(0,orderedArray.size());
      }

    }
```

Comment: Probably the jar is not in the classpath. Could you please confirm that? also please tell which jar are you using?

Comment: I'm using JUnit 4.12 and the jar should be in the classpath. I'm able to compile a similar test in the same folder.

Comment: Ok, I was making a mistake with the classpath. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find symbol assertEquals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631621/cannot-find-symbol-assertequals)

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a *Static import*

The line `import org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;` is referencing the method `assertArrayEquals` from the class `org.junit.Assert`

Importing a static method so that it is callable like `assertEquals(0,orderedArray.size());` is done with a static import line. Try out the following:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

Alternatively you can:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

, or you could:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
```

and reference the methods like

```
Assert.assertEquals(0,orderedArray.size());
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have the [JUnit dependency](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install) in the classpath, use `import static` for the assert methods:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

Or simply use:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Comment: Ok, I was making a mistake with the classpath. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the keyword `static` to import it. An example:

```
 import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
```

Comment: Addind the keyword gives me the following error:  package org.junit does not exist

Answer (score 0):

If you are using junit version 5 and above then use org.junit.jupiter.api.assertions .

Path has been moved in junit 5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).