# How to import all Android classes in a .java file in ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am currently learning to develop apps for Android-based devices, and I have a pretty decent hold on Java, so learning hasn't been too challenging for me. However, I am lazy, and I don't want to import each individual Android class that I need. In one of my .java files, if I was to type:

```
import android.*;
```

It would compile fine. However, if I was to type:

```
public class example extends Activity{...}
```

Below the former piece of code, Eclipse/ADT still tells me I need to import the android.app.Activity class. So, is there another way I could import all the android classes in order for me to save the time of importing each one individually?

If not, I'll be a good sport and get over it, but it would be really convenient, nonetheless.

Comment: Please read [Why is using a wild card with a java import statement bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad). Furthermore, use the fix imports shortcut, it will do it for you.

Comment: I read the piece you gave me, and I will take your help. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is there another way I could import all the android classes in order for me to save the time of importing each one individually?

`import android.*;` will only import classes and interfaces that are *directly* in the `android` package. To import all classes/interfaces in `android.app`, use `import android.app.*;`.

Bear in mind that Eclipse/ADT provides multiple ways of adding the imports for you, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to resolve all missing imports.

Comment: That's understandable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Eclipse/Adt setting "Organize Imports" in Java ->Editor -> Save Actions to allow Eclipse organize your imports on save. Very useful.
Also you can customize the setting in Java -> Code Style -> Organize Imports.