# Loading Java class path via wildcard or not?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I see a lot of opensource project use `-cp` as

```
java -cp "libs/a.jar:libs/b.jar:libs/c.jar"
```

instead of

```
java -cp "libs/*"
```

Are there any reason?

Comment: This an approved standard. Also this is a duplicate that has been asked a number of times, do your research first.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad

Comment: @Dave That question is imports, not classpath. Also, `import` is just syntactic sugar--it doesn't change anything about your compiled classes, it doesn't change the size or nature of your bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to import via wildcards wasn't available until Java 6 (IIRC).

I prefer explicit dependencies since you know what you're actually using, and can avoid importing potentially conflicting jars, but for simple apps it's not really an issue.

Comment: Or better yet, have a tool do that for you.