# 1 error! "Main.java:30: error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

I cant seem to get he code I wrote for my Java programming class to work.

```
/*Coby Bushong
Java Programming
Professor Lehman
August 9th 2014*/

import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner class

/*This program will calculate the commission of a stock broker
at a 2% commission given the number of shares at a contant rate.*/

public class StockCommission 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //Constants
      final double STOCK_VALUE = 21.77;       //price per share
      final double BROKER_COMMISSION = 0.02;  //broker commission rate

      //variables
      double shares;     //To hold share amount
      double shareValue; //To hold total price of shares
      double commission; //To hold commission
      double total;      //To hold total cost

      //create scanner for keyboard input
      Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      //creates dialog box for user input
      String inputShares;
      inputShares = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many stocks do you own?");
      shares = Integer.parseInt(inputShares);

      //calculate total
      shareValue = shares * STOCK_VALUE;

      //calculate commission
      commission = shareValue * BROKER_COMMISSION;

      //calculate total
      total = commission + shareValue;

      //display results
      System.out.println("Shares Owned:" + shares);
      System.out.println("Value of Shares:         $" + shareValue);
      System.out.println("Comission:         $" + commission);
      System.out.println("Total:       $" + total);
   }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Errors: 1

StockCommission.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
  inputShares = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many stocks do you own?");
                ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, you have to specify where you want to find a class. Here, that class is `JOptionPane`. It is located in the `javax.swing` package.

You can read about using packages in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html). Basically, you'll have to either

- use the fully qualified class name:

  ```
  inputShares = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many stocks do you own?");
  ```
- import the class or the whole package in the top of the file:

  ```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  ```

  or

  ```
  import javax.swing.*;
  ```

  The latter method of importing the whole package is generally considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad), so I would not recommend doing that.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the wildcard import is discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

You have to *import* the `JOptionPane` class; add this at the top of the file:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```