# Is using import java.util.* undesirable?

Tags: java, import

Is using

```
 import java.util.*
```

not favorable compared to calling on the specific packages? I was wondering if its *significantly* inefficient to a program to call on all the packages, rather than listing them out specifically such as:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Math;
```

etc. I am preparing for interviews and want to make sure I have good coding practices.

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you. I'm wondering if interviewers will not appreciate that I'm using import java.util.*? (Since I probably will be dealing with a small program)

Comment: If you are going to write code on paper then I would say using wildcards `*` is OK (you can leave comment near each one of `*` to describe which classes from this package you are going to use to show that there will be no conflict with other `*`), if you will be able to use IDE then prefer explicit imports (Eclipse can organize them for you with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`O`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with importing * is that it increases the chance of naming conflicts.

Let's assume that in your program, you have a class called `EventListener`, since `java.util` also has a class called `EventListener`, right the way you have some conflicts to deal with, but you do not even care that `java.util.EventListener` in this context.

This really can be avoided, simply by not importing * and only importing specific classes that are truly needed.

Comment: I've sometimes run into trouble by importing the `java.awt` and `java.util` packages with the asterisk and then attempting to use the `List` interface of the `java.util` package, forgetting that the `List` class exists in the `java.awt` package. The compiler won't be able to tell if you want to use the class/interface from one package or the other.

Comment: @TNT In that case beside `.*` wildcards you can add explicit import of `List` you want to use, like `import java.awt.*; import java.util.*; import java.util.List;` (last import will let compiler determine from which package `List` should be used).

Comment: @Pshemo That's a good point. I usually just put the package name in front of the class name in these situations, i.e. `java.util.List list ...`

Answer (score 0):

@PeterPeiGuo is right, besides that, I want to say I don't use import xxx.xx.*, cause as a developer you need to know which class you should use and which class not. You need to understand everything for your code/application. So import xxx.xx.XXX is better from my view.