# effects of extra imported classes in java

Tags: java, android, import, classloader

in http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

I read about use fully qualify imports. But I am curious about the negative affects of not using imports explicitly. For instance, if I use the following code

```
package blabla;
import foo.*;
import hee.*;
import lee.*;
...
...
public class ImportKing {
...
}
```

from my understanding, when this class--ImportKing is used anywhere in the project, the classloader will load any classes it imported, therefore will consume extra system memory for needless imports.

testing code:

```
//import java.*;
public class ImportKing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("running");
        }
    }
}
```

testing result:

USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

shanwu    3316 39.8  0.6 3182012 52196 pts/0   Sl+  09:25   0:03 java ImportKing with extra imports

shanwu    3440 43.7  0.6 3182012 52752 pts/0   Sl+  09:27   0:03 java ImportKing without extra imports

I didn't see any negative effects on program performance for extra imports. Is extra imports handled by java compiler, so we don't have problem like wasting system memory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad

Comment: @Voicu thanks, that answer also explains parts of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q:  the classloader will load any classes it imported,

A: No, the class loader will be invoked when a class is needed (for example, calling a constructor).  This has nothing to do with "imports" in your source code.

Q: therefore will consume extra system memory for needless imports.

A: No: classes are not loaded needlessly; memory is *not* "wasted".

SUGGESTION:

Here are two good links on the basics of Java class loading:

- http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html
- http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0808/chaudhri/

Here is what the Java specification has to say about "import":

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5
>
> An import declaration makes types or members available by their simple
>   names only within the compilation unit that actually contains the
>   import declaration. The scope of the type(s) or member(s) introduced
>   by an import declaration specifically does not include the PackageName
>   of a package declaration, other import declarations in the current
>   compilation unit, or other compilation units in the same package.

An "import" is a compile-time construct to simplify identifying a "name" with (perhaps one of many different) "class definition(s)".  It does *not* affect runtime behavior; it is completely *seperate* from "class loading".

Answer (score 2):

An `import` statement does absolutely nothing at runtime.

An `import` statement simply makes it possible for you to use simple names of types (and their members) in your source code rather than fully qualified names.

Comment: could you give me more detail on extra import handling?

Comment: @shanwu What would you like to know?

Comment: how does java handle extra imports?

Comment: @shanwu What do you mean _extra imports_? Do you mean wildcard `*`? It makes all the types in that package available to be used with their simple type names.

Comment: how does java handle wildcard * ? for example, if those classes are needless, how does java handle those needless imported classes?

Comment: @shanwu At compile time, _only_ if a type is used in the source code, its class will be looked up. The compiler will use it to verify any use of the type in the source code: method calls, field accesses, etc.