# How does "import *" work in Java?

Tags: java, package

If, in `import java.*` the `*` includes all the packages, then why do have to write `import java.lang.*` and `import java.util.*`?

Comment: Classes only. If you use `import static`, it will import `static` members of a class.

Comment: java.* will include the class in the java folder only not in its sub folders so you have to specify the class in sub folders

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is using a wild card with a Java import statement bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad)

Answer (score 5):

```
import packagename.*;
```

imports all classes, interfaces ect. from the package `packagename` but not "subpackages", i.e. `import java.*;` imports all classes from the `java` package, but no classes from `java.util`. Since there are no classes in the `java` package, using `import java.*` imports nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Even though typically packages map to file system directories, there is not a hierarchical relationship between packages. A package `com.initech` is not the parent of `com.initech.tps`, they are two separate packages with no relationship between them. You can't refer to multiple subpackages with a wildcard because as far as the compiler is concerned there is no such thing as a "subpackage". `java.lang` is a package, `java.util` is a package, but `java` is not a package.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example
Suppose you have one package called base.. And inside it you have package called child1..
Base package also have two classes in it..b1 and b2
And your child1 package also have some classes into it..c1,c2..
Then when you write
import base.* 
it only imports classes of base package i.e b1 and b2 not the child package classes...
And when you write
import base.child1.*
It imports all classes in child1 package....