# Java array with enums

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I experimented a little with enums and arrays in Java:

```
enum animals
  {CAT, DOG, COW, BIRD, POTATO}
```

To get this into an array I simply do this...

```
animals[] creatures = {animals.CAT, animals.POTATO};
```

But now if I have to define bigger entries, I thought it would be useful if I can just type in the enumeration **without animals.XXX**, like I also do in C++

```
animals[] creatures = {CAT, POTATO, BIRD, CAT, CAT, POTATO, COW...}
```

- It would take time and gives me a better overview
- Java already knows that my target type is 'animals', so in my opinion this is unnecessary (?)

So I just wondered if this is possible in any way, and why if not?

Comment: Note also that there is an apparent discrepancy between what you wrote above and the `switch` syntax for enums: the `cases` in such switch statements _cannot_ be `case animals.CAT:` etc. but instead they _must_ be `case CAT:` unlike their use in an array initializer. So you could augment your question by asking, if I can (in fact must) leave out the qualifier in `case` statements why can't I do the same in array initializers? (And vice versa of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java mandates that you use the fully classified name to use it. For standard classes, this is generally done by importing a package with `import name.of.package` and then using the simple name of the class. For static fields, like enum constants, you can use static imports.

```
import static animals.CAT;
import static animals.POTATO;
import static animals.BIRD;
import static animals.COW;

// ...

animals[] creatures = {CAT, POTATO, BIRD, CAT, CAT, POTATO, COW...};
```

---

You could also use

```
import static animals.*;
```

avoiding the need to import every animals, but note that the first construct [is generally considered better than the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/147454/1743880).

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think of this, but it seems very reasonable and works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

While there are other solutions that will work, you don't have to really go through any of that.  What you can do instead is use the `values()` array to pull in all of the present values attached to the array instead.

That is, if you really want to have an array called `creatures` that contains all entries of your enum, you can express that as this:

```
// Classes, interfaces, and enums should start with an upper case
Animals[] creatures = Animals.values();
```

If you add a new entry to the enum it will be automatically pulled in through `values()`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `enum` should be named `Animals`, since types should start with an uppercase letter.

The reason you have to qualify the values in the array initializer, is because each value of the initializer is a full-blown expression.

```
int x = <expression>;
int[] x = {<expression>, <expression>, ...};
Animals x = <expression>;
Animals[] x = {<expression>, <expression>, ...};
```

The only place an `enum` value doesn't need to be qualified, is in a `switch` statement, because the value of a `case` must be a constant, not an expression:

```
switch (animal) {
    case CAT:
        // code
        break;
    case DOG:
        // code
        break;
}
```

Outside of that you have to qualify, unless of course you import the enum values using `import static`.

Answer (score 1):

Below should do it

```
animals[] creatures = {animal.CAT, animal.POTATO, animal.BIRD, CAT};
```