# internal versus external libraries Java

Tags: java, import, libraries, java-io

What is the difference between internal and external libraries in Java?

For example,

```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.io.File;
```

Is java.util and/or java.io an internal library, external library, or something else?
Thanks!

Comment: Internal libraries are the ones that are provided by Sun/Oracle and shipped as part of JDK. External libraries are from third parties provided as a JAR, which you would add to class path to access the resources. Example: Apache Logging library - log4j.jar

Comment: It is not libraries but packages. It allows you to write your code using simple class names like `ArrayList` but at the same time it lets compiler compile such names with their full names like `java.util.ArrayList`. Generally it is better to avoid `.*` (more info: [Why is using a wild card with a Java import statement bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad)).

Comment: All imports that start with java are from jdk so they are internal

Comment: Anyway your question is unclear. Your title is about internal/external libraries but post is about importing package where both imports are using standard Java packages/classes. Can you clarify your question more?

Comment: @Pshemo I confused packages with libraries. So java.util and java.io are packages and have nothing to do with internal/external libraries... my mistake!

Comment: Libraries (in sense of JAR files) can contain many packages which in turn can contain many`.class` files. So they are related but are not the same. Consider using [edit] option to clarify your question. For now it is still unclear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, an *internal* library is either "a library that is provided as *(effectively)* "part of the language itself," or "a library that is known only to your (big) project."  In one case, only the language-vendor has control of it. In the other, only you do.

An *external* library is something that comes from an outside source. (Hence, neither you nor the language-vendor "owns" it.) Your project *references* it, and *depends on* (a certain version of) it such that "it cannot live without it," but it is not "(just) a part of *this* project."