# how to import multiple packages in one java file?

Tags: java, package

How can I import multiple packages in one java file. For example if I created a main method in one java file and packages in different. I want to import 3 packages in one line then how can I import all in one line?

Comment: I suggest you look for a tutorial on Java packages and Java imports.  You seem to be fundamentally confused about the concepts.  Maybe https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-package/ and https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-imports/ (I'm not recommending them, I just found them with Google).

Comment: import it like `import  java.mypackage`

Answer (score 5):

In Java, you can import entire package using `*`. to import multiple packages. e.g. `import com.package1.*;` to import everything from package1. To import multiple packages, e.g.
`import com.package1.*;
import com.package2.*;
import com.package3.*;`

Importing on a single line like `import package1.*,package2.*,package3.*;` is not possible in java but you can import entire directory if the packages are in the same directory as in `import com.*;`

Comment: Also using the wildcard `*` doesn't lead to unnecessary class loadings, as Java selectively chooses only the classes it needs in compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard `*` can import everything from a single package:

```
import junit.*;
```

Just be sure you don't [clutter your local namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad) with classes you are not using. If you're using a Java IDE, consider using the Organize Imports feature (ctrl-shift-o in Eclipse) instead.