# import * vs import { specificName } in Typescript/ES6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, amd

Declaration

```
declare module "MyModule" {

export function Foo() {...}
export function Bar() {...}

}
```

I just need Foo somewhere, how should I import it ?

```
import * as MyModule from "MyModule";

MyModule.Foo();
```

or

```
import {Foo} from "MyModule";
Foo()
```

Which one is better than another ? Are there any performance implications of importing all the exports in the first way?

Some references which I read before posting questions:

https://www.exratione.com/2015/12/es6-use-of-import-property-from-module-is-not-a-great-plan/

Comment: Why is `* as MyModule` even under consideration here if all you need is `Foo`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad

Comment: @SandeepRoy I am talking about javascript and here it is not cluttering namespace.

Comment: @estus https://www.exratione.com/2015/12/es6-use-of-import-property-from-module-is-not-a-great-plan/

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked before commenting.

Comment: TypeScript and JS/Babel imports work differently.
TS: Default import is import * from 'some-package'. To have named or default imports(import {module_name} from 'some-package' or import default_module_name from 'some_package') we need to enable esModuleInterop flag(esModuleInterop: true) in tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 7):

Importing only what is **necessary** to your code is, of course, **good practice**. Say someone writes some thousand-line code importing everything, and then you try to analyze it. Do you think you would easily know which functions used in your code are imported or which is not? Obviously it is dubious and **bad practice**.

With regards performance, I suppose not much affected.

Answer (score 6):

The `import {} from ...` syntax makes stubbing and spying on functions very difficult and normally requires additional libraries such as rewire.js. The caveat is tree shaking doesn't work as well. I'm inclined to keep my util modules small and maybe only include 2-3 functions per module. That way I can use the `import * as ...` syntax for my modules and `import {} ...` when possible for third party modules. Thus minimising the need for tree shaking.

Comment: This blog post provides additional information which supports this answer: https://www.exratione.com/2015/12/es6-use-of-import-property-from-module-is-not-a-great-plan/

Comment: I noticed that import * as Foo from ... behaves differently than import Foo from ... where stubbing works for later but not former in jest. Strange..

Comment: if the tools you're using don't support stubbing `import { foo } from './bar';` then get better tools.

Comment: "The caveat is tree shaking doesn't work as well." Could you point to some docs about this? Tree shaking seems to work for me with both import styles. I'm using webpack, maybe it's a new development during the past couple years?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use *only* `Foo`, I think it's better to import just `Foo`. This makes your code clearer, because by looking at that import you can tell which elements of `MyModule` that code is using.

It doesn't affect performance, because either way you have to read/download the whole file.

Also, it doesn't matter which option you choose when using a bundler like Rollup.js―even if you import everything from `MyModule`, the bundle will include only things that you actually use in your code.

Comment: I don't think we are using any bundler which supports treeshaking.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for answers, i have shared my thoughts on this.

- Let say you have a JSON file and you want to import the entire module as a variable then go with `import *`.
- If you have a module with multiple exported methods (That can be 3rd party packages), then you should go with `import {}` approach.
- Any default export should be imported as "import `any name`".