# mvn package org.apache.pdfbox not found

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, pdfbox

I have these imports (among others):

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
```

I have this dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I see this line in my eclipse maven dependencies:

```
pdfbox-2.0.4.jar - C:\Users\Paul\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox\2.0.4\pdfbox-2.0.4.jar
```

I check the build path in eclipse, and see pdfbox-2.0.4.jar in the Maven Dependencies part.

I run mvn clean compile in a command prompt (Windows).

I get the error "package org.apache.pdfbox does not exist"

I run mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt

The following lines are listed in the class path (at the front of the class path):

```
C:\Users\Paul\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox\2.0.4\pdfbox-2.0.4.jar;
C:\Users\Paul\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\fontbox\2.0.4\fontbox-2.0.4.jar;
```

I look in C:\Users\Paul.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox\2.0.4\
and I see pdfbox-2.0.4.jar

So what am I missing? Why is the pdfbox jar not being found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this line:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.*;
```

because that package does indeed not exist. The other ones (with deeper levels) are OK.

Comment: That certainly worked. I am a little confused why the * didn't import all, but I guess that doesn't really matter. Thanks so very.

Comment: there is no package on the level you used, which is the top level of the core pdfbox subproject. What would have worked is `import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;`. But you shouldn't use * for imports anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad

Comment: Thanks again! I appreciate the follow up.