# Why C# "using aliases" are not used by default?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

Consider the following code.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        [Required, MaxLength(250)]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Unless you have a fancy IDE (that is doing all sorts lookups & static analysis behind the scenes) it's pretty ambiguous as to where "Required" & "MaxLength" actually come from. Especially when several namespaces might be imported, with similar meaning.

As a relative newbie to C# I am finding myself always having a hard time figuring out where certain things come from. Especially when looking at other code snippets on places like StackOverflow.

```
using DataAnnotations = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        [DataAnnotations.Required, DataAnnotations.MaxLength(250)]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now it's very obvious where "Required" & "MaxLength" come from. You could take it another step and do something like:

```
using Required = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute;
using MaxLength = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute;

namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        [Required, MaxLength(250)]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is now very similar to how both PHP & Js ES6 works.

I'm curious as to why this isn't the default for C#? And why pretty much every other C# dev I have spoken with considers alias's bad practice? Is there some underlying performance reason perhaps?

Comment: I think you have the answer in your question: "Unless you have a fancy IDE". I would imagine a vast majority of C# developers are working in Visual Studio. I doubt performance has any impact, this would be a compile time thing.

Comment: @OP What you're suggesting would result in a `using` statement for every type you use in every .cs file. If you're using 10 types from the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace, do you want 10 `using` statements, or one?

Comment: In such a case I would still only have one using statement. `using DataAnnotations = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` Its about tying the actual use of something to it's `using` statement.

Comment: @BradJones Then you have to type `DataAnnotations.[TypeName]` instead of just `[TypeName]` every time you access one of those types. Does that really benefit anybody? I think it just makes the code unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: In what context are you referring to the concept of "Default"?  You're the one writing the code, you can "Default" it to whatever you write it as.  Sure, those "fancy" editors you just disregarded could auto-insert something like this, but the whole point you were making is what if you're not using that fancy editor.. so your question really doesn't make much sense and contradicts itself.

Comment: You are not alone in sometimes feeling "lost" in C# codebases. C++ has the same problem. ES6 does a lot better here, PHP a bit less so but still better than C#.

Comment: @Brad is this a fair representation of the question?: What (if anything) makes C# dev different from dev in other languages where bulk imports are commonly regarded as bad practice or for special uses?: E.g. the equivalent of `using System;` is prohibited by google style guides for [C++](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Namespaces), [python](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#224-decision), and [java](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.3.1-wildcard-imports), but not for [C#](https://google.github.io/styleguide/csharp-style.html#using).

Comment: @Brad I think the above version is fact-based and might fly if you're willing to agree or edit. Also, the following deal with the same principle in other languages: [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad), [go](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29326). I think the question here is if/why these arguments wouldn't be equally valid for C# dev. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why does it matter where types/definitions come from?

If you're truly that concerned about what namespace a type is present in, Visual Studio has the ability to find out in *several* ways, the two that are my favourite are below:

- **Hover the type / declaration.** This often shows you the full type-name. (Hovering a `new SomeType()` statement shows you the method name, which is what is applied to attributes.)
- **Press F12 / Go To Definition.** Even if you don't have the source for the definition, using the <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Right Click</kbd> -> <kbd>Go To Definition</kbd> will take you to the metadata file that shows you all the public members of the type. This doesn't work on keywords (`out`, `ref`, `return`, `null`, etc.) but it works on basic aliased types (`int`, `string`, etc.) and traditional types (`enum`, `interface`, `class`, `struct`, etc.). This includes the namespace, type-name, and all public API members. If there are XML docs they are included as well. If you <kbd>F12</kbd> an extension-method it takes you to the class metadata *for that extension method*. This is *extremely* helpful for identifying where a method came from if you feel it was injected by something it *shouldn't* have been.

So now it's not *really* that difficult the determine what namespace that the type came from. So what about the `using` aliases, when do we *actually* need them?

Real life scenario: I have been working on a Windows Forms model for the XNA Framework. XNA Framework has a `Color` type, and my framework has a `Color` type. Now I often use both those namespaces together but only need *one* of the `Color` types to be used natively. Often times I have a list of `using` statements that include something like:

```
using XnaColor = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color;
using Color = Evbpc.Framework.Drawing.Color;
```

So this resolves an *ambiguity* issue.

## Why aren't `using` aliases a default?

Probably because they're *almost never* necessary. We don't *really* need them. If you're concerned about what namespace a type comes from it's *far* easier to do a quick lookup than it is to alias everything and **force** a namespace to be defined. At that rate you may-as-well bar `using` statements altogether and fully-qualify everything.

The biggest two use-cases I've **ever** had for a `using` alias are:

1. **Resolve ambiguity between types.** See example above.
2. **Resolve ambiguity between namespaces.** Same idea as above, but I alias a whole namespace if a lot of types are duplicated.

   ```
   using XnaF = Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
   using Evbpc.Framework.Drawing;
   ```

If you're generating code with Visual Studio, importing types, etc., it's *not* going to use an alias. Visual Studio will, instead, fully-qualify the name as necessary. Ever right-click a squiggle and get `A.B.Type` as the only option instead of `using A.B`? *Well that's usually a good spot for an alias.*

I'll warn you though, `using` aliases seem to increase maintainability requirements. (This may not have numbers backed up, but I won't lie - this project that I have several aliases in causes me to forget how/what I named an alias *frequently*.)

Generally, in my experience, if you have to use a `using` alias, you are *probably* breaking a rule somewhere.

## Why don't we *even* use them on a regular basis?

Because they suck. They make code harder to read (take your example of `DataAnnotations.MaxLength`, why do I need to read that? I don't care that `MaxLength` is in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, I only care that it's set properly), they disorganize code (now I am **forced** to remember that an attribute is in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` instead of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`), and they are just generally clunky.

Take your previous example, I have an Entity Framework project which has attributes something like the following on a class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
[MaxLength(128)]
public string UserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Now with your example I would have one of the following:

> ```
> using DataAnnotations = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
>
> [DataAnnotations.Key, DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(Order = 2)]
> [DataAnnotations.MaxLength(128)]
> public string UserId { get; set; }
>
> [DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
> public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
> ```

Or:

> ```
> using DataAnnotations = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
> using Schema = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
>
> [DataAnnotations.Key, Schema.Column(Order = 2)]
> [DataAnnotations.MaxLength(128)]
> public string UserId { get; set; }
>
> [Schema.ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
> public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
> ```

Or worse yet:

> ```
> using KeyAttribute = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute;
> using MaxLengthAttribute = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute;
> using ColumnAttribute = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute;
> using ForeignKeyAttribute = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKeyAttribute;
>
> [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
> [MaxLength(128)]
> public string UserId { get; set; }
>
> [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
> public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
> ```

I'm sorry, but those are just *terrible*. This is why 'every' dev you talk to avoids them and thinks this is a bad idea. I'll just stick to *intelligently*<sup>[1]</sup> importing namespaces and deal with the *very minute* potential that types clash. **Then** I'll use an alias.

If you *really* cannot find what namespace a type is in (say you pull code from Stack Overflow) then hit up [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/), go to the [Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library) and search for the type. (I.e., search for `KeyAttribute` or `MaxLengthAttribute` and the first links are the API references.)

<sub>[1]: By *intelligently* I mean doing so with responsibility and care. Don't just *blindly* import / use namespaces, try to limit them as much as possible. SRP and polymorphism usually allow us to keep the `using` list pretty small in each file.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @EBrown, I think it's just something I have to get used to. Just found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/ which has been super helpful.