# Package java does not exists

Tags: java

I want to import java.sql but it says **Package java does not exist**
I am using Netbeans.

Here is the picture:
Screenshot Netbeans

[image]

The hint showing in Netbeans is **Remove unused import** only.

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: You either import a specific class (recommended) in the package, or all the classes in the package using `*` (not recommended).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.sql import not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840641/java-sql-import-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

`import java.sql` is an invalid import.

Either use `Ctrl + Shift + I` in NetBeans to "Fix Imports" (if you try to use a class in your code that is not imported yet)

Or you import all classes under `java.sql` package with `import java.sql.*;`

Or you import the specific class you need, eg `import java.sql.Connection;`