# Import multiple classes from one package

Tags: java

What difference between

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List; //1

import java.util.*; //2
```

Will I import all classes from `java.util` in case 2 or only necessary? Is additional bytes will be added to class file in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad

Comment: @JackFlamp yeah that would've been a more straightforward dupe.

Comment: Chek [The Java™ Tutorials's **Using Package Members** Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import java.util.*` will import all classes, but only the ones you actually use will be in the compiled code. It does not affect your program once it is compiled. 
It only makes the compilation a little bit longer (probably talking milliseconds here), but nothing we can see, so just use whichever way you prefer/ is clearer.