# Why does 'import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.ChiSquaredDistribution' work and 'import org.apache.commons.math3' doesnt?

Tags: java, import

I am very new to java and I was trying to use a package to sample some Chisquared distributed random variables . When I try to import the entire org.apache.commons.math3 package using

'import org.apache.commons.math3

I get an error and my code doesn't complile giving a import error
 but when I use
 import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.ChiSquaredDistribution;

Is this because we have to import specific classes and we cant import entire libraries.

Comment: try `import org.apache.commons.math3.*` , I'm not experienced with apache but the `*` normally imports all parts of the package.

Comment: You can't import packages but you can import all classes within a package via `import your.package.*;` - note that this doesn't include subpackages.

Comment: org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.ChiSquaredDistribution is  a sub-package of  import org.apache.commons.math3? Is that why when I import using  import org.apache.commons.math3.* , I cant access ChiSquaredDistribution class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't import packages but you can import all classes within a package via `import your.package.*;` - note that this doesn't include subpackages.

Thus using `import org.apache.commons.math3.*;` you could use all classes in that package but not classes like `ChiSquaredDistribution` because that one is in the subpackage `distribution`. You'd need `import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.*;` for that.

Alternatively you use a decent IDE and let it generate the import statements for you - no need to do that yourself (and [you shouldn't use wildcard imports anyways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad))

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import everything within the math3 folder by adding .* at the end.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.*
```

Comment: The error goes away but I cant use the classes explicitly , so whats the point ?