# Generics: Type argument is not within its bounds

Tags: eclipse, generics, kotlin

Any idea why the following code wouldn't compile?

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> naturalSort(list: List<T>): List<T> {
  val natComparator = naturalOrder<T>() // compiler error here

  return list.sortedWith(natComparator)
}
```

The second line results in the compiler error:

> Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'Comparable'

**Update**:
It works for me in https://play.kotlinlang.org/ but fails in Eclipse and when building the project (from Eclipse) with the project's Gradle build script.

Here's how my Gradle build environment looks like:

https://pastebin.com/0GDUWy2C

Comment: Which version of Kotlin are you using? Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Same here: no problems, works as expected: https://pl.kotl.in/rwy-h4b97

Comment: It works for me too in https://play.kotlinlang.org/ but fails in Eclipse and when building the project (from Eclipse) with the project's Gradle build script.

Here's how my Gradle build environment looks like:

https://pastebin.com/0GDUWy2C

Answer (score 2):

Might not be relevant to this case but maybe someone would have the similar case as me: I had a similar problem with Mui Material components (for Autocomplete and Textfield). For me the solution was to suppress the warnings. This was my code:

```
Autocomplete<AutocompleteProps<String>> { ... }
```

This was the error I was getting:

```
Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'ChildrenBuilder'
```

And the solution for me was to add this suppress before the view's class declaration:

```
@Suppress("UPPER_BOUND_VIOLATED")
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was caused by the wrong `Comparable` interface being used <strike>due to import statements in the actual code</strike> (no problem with the import statements, not really sure why java.lang.Comparable was used instead of kotlin.Comparable). Specifying in the code that `kotlin.Comparable` should be used resolves the issue:

`fun <T : kotlin.Comparable<T>> naturalSort(list: List<T>): List<T> {
    val natComparator = naturalOrder<T>() // no error
    return list.sortedWith(natComparator)
}`

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: I guess you may be interested in this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad

Comment: Actually, no wildcard imports or excessive imports were used (6 classes imported total), that's why it was so surprising.