# Ktlint doesn't allow wildcard import? (Using IntelliJ auto import feature)

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, ktlint

I am running a Kotlin project with ktlint maven plugin (first time user). but whenever I do a maven build. I often see the failure along the lines of

```
src/main/kotlin/com/myproject/model/User.kt:7:1: Wildcard import (cannot be auto-corrected)
```

Since I use IntelliJ, I often rely on auto import where many subpackages are grouped into a wildcard (*). Is this what ktline used to enforce good import practices?

Comment: So your question is why ktlint doesn't allow wildcard imports?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad) one can help you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of version 0.34 or thereabouts you can override individual rules via [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/). Add this to your `.editorconfig` file in the root of the project:

```
[*.{kt,kts}]
ktlint_no-wildcard-imports = disabled
```

https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/faq/#how-do-i-globally-disable-a-rule

Comment: Alec could you please add an example here?

Comment: @YashPokar Added. Weird that they removed documentation from their Github page.

Comment: `disabled_rules` is deprecated as of ktlint 0.48. The supported way to do this is now: `ktlint_no-wildcard-imports = disabled`

Answer (score 11):

ktlint changed the rule layout in `.editorconfig` (again). Now it has to be:

```
ktlint_standard_no-wildcard-imports = disabled
```

Comment: This is the working solution now, starting version 0.49.0 of ktlint. Thanks @mattelacchiato

Comment: Somebody move this answer up!

Comment: Do you mean `.editorconfig`?

Answer (score 7):

I was using [ktlint-gradle](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle) and using the command `./gradlew ktlintCheck` and my .editorconfig wasn't getting picked up. I solved it by adding this to `build.gradle`

```
ktlint {
    disabledRules.set(setOf("no-wildcard-imports"))
}
```

Comment: This stopped working lately with the following error `UserData should not contain '.editorconfig' properties [disabled_rules]. Such properties should be passed via the 'ExperimentalParams.editorConfigOverride' field. Note that this is only required for properties that (potentially) contain a value that differs from the actual value in the '.editorconfig' file.` Use the accepted answer instead