# How to use user input from tkinter in a list to randomly choose using choice() from random module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made two entries for the user, then I took them and turned them into a string using the `str()`, then put them in a list and put that list in choice from the random module and turned that into a string using `str()` and put it in a function that turns the text into a label and that puts it onto the screen. then the button runs that function.

I was expecting 2 entry boxes and on button underneath it like:

> ENTRY BOX
>
> ENTRY BOX
>
> BUTTON

And after that it takes the two things and randomly chooses between the two of them. Then the button would stick it onto the screen.
Here's my code:

```
            opt_1 = Entry(win, width=40)
            opt_1.focus_set()
            opt_1.pack()
            opt_2 = Entry(win, width=40)
            opt_2.focus_set()
            opt_2.pack()
            opt_1str = str(opt_1.get())
            opt_2str = str(opt_2.get())
            choice_list = [opt_1str, opt_2str]
            rando_choice = choice(choice_list)
            ai_rando_choice = str(rando_choice)
            def output_answer():
                output = Label(win, text=ai_rando_choice, font="Courier 9 bold")
                output.pack()

            tk.Button(win, text="GO!", width=20, command=output_answer).pack(pady=20)
```

It's in a switch case and here's the rest of the code if it helps.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from random import *

win = Tk()

win.geometry("750x750")


# function time

def display_answer():
    global output
    entri = choice.get()
    match entri:
        case "0":
            output = Label(win, text="Then why are you here? dang this generation is getting dumber and dumber.",
                           font="Courier 9 bold")
            output.pack()
        case "1":
            opt_1 = Entry(win, width=40)
            opt_1.focus_set()
            opt_1.pack()

            def output_answer():
                output = Label(win, text="Uh-hh " + opt_1.get() + "?? I dunno, what do you want? You only gave me one, "
                                                                  "dang this generation is really dumb", font="Courier "
                                                                                                              "9 bold")
                output.pack()

            tk.Button(win, text="GO!", width=20, command=output_answer).pack(pady=20)
        case "2":
            opt_1 = Entry(win, width=40)
            opt_1.focus_set()
            opt_1.pack()
            opt_2 = Entry(win, width=40)
            opt_2.focus_set()
            opt_2.pack()
            opt_1str = str(opt_1.get())
            opt_2str = str(opt_2.get())
            choice_list = [opt_1str, opt_2str]
            rando_choice = choice(choice_list)
            ai_rando_choice = str(rando_choice)
            def output_answer():
                output = Label(win, text=ai_rando_choice, font="Courier 9 bold")
                output.pack()

            tk.Button(win, text="GO!", width=20, command=output_answer).pack(pady=20)


# Initialize a Label to display the User Input
instructions = Label(win, text="type in how many decisions you have (max 10) \n↓\n", font="Courier 14 bold")
instructions.pack()

# Create an Entry widget to accept User Input
choice = Entry(win, width=40)
choice.focus_set()
choice.pack()

# Create a Button to validate Entry Widget
tk.Button(win, text="Okay", width=20, command=display_answer).pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Basic issue is that you are generation the value of `ai_rando_choice` outside of the function. It generates the value once at initialisation where its "options" are `["",""]`. Move the retrieving of the strings and the generating of the random choice into the function so that it is re-evaluated when the function is called.

Comment: Umm I tried putting the ai_rando_choice inside of the function but that still didn't change the fact that I'm still getting this error
  File "C:\Users\arjun\PycharmProjects\python games\option chooser.py", line 42, in display_answer
    rando_choice = choice(choice_list)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'Entry' object is not callable 
I really don't understand

Comment: You have conflicting names, since you did `from random import *` and also `choice = Entry(...)`. Fix the conflict, and remember that this is why [wildcard imports are not recommended](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) in [many if not most languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad).

Comment: Thanks that worked in getting the error off an I figured ou that I have tograb the entries in the function and also randomly choose in the function Thanks again!